# grails generate-all is throwing an error

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am running a grails 2.3.5 app. I get an error when I try to run

```
 grails generate-all tao.marketing.blog.TrainerInfo --stacktrace
```

Does anybody have an idea for me where to look at. It looks like the ST library is causeing the problem. I placed it in the lib directory. Do I need to define it anywhere else?

```
Thomass-MacBook-Pro:tao thomas$ grails generate-all tao.marketing.blog.TrainerInfo --stacktrace
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
    | Packaging Grails application.....
    2017-03-05 14:55:08,066 [main] INFO  conf.Config  - catalinaBase: null
    2017-03-05 14:55:08,066 [main] INFO  conf.Config  - catalinaBase: null
    2017-03-05 14:55:11,445 [main] INFO  conf.Config  - catalinaBase: null
    2017-03-05 14:55:11,445 [main] INFO  conf.Config  - catalinaBase: null
    | Error Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
    at _GrailsBootstrap_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsBootstrap_groovy:31)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:36)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at GenerateAll$_run_closure1.doCall(GenerateAll:42)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 39 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/stringtemplate/v4/ST
    ... 39 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.stringtemplate.v4.ST
    ... 39 more
    | Error Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
    Thomass-MacBook-Pro:tao thomas$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define it in BuildConfig.groovy. Then it worked out fine!

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile ":ST:4.0.8"
    ...
}
```